# Updating a webpart - Which gulp commands do I need to be running?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have a couple webparts locally hosted for my SPO environment. I'm using a Team Site Library to host the "temp" files and the .sppkg file is hosted through the App catalog. When I want to make an update to the webpart, I've been doing the following:

1. `gulp package-solution`
2. `gulp bundle --ship`
3. `gulp package-solution --ship`

Then uploading the .sppkg file to the App catalog and the "temp" files to the team site (then deleting the old files from the Team Site). Area any of these steps unnecessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gulp package-solution --ship
```

that should be enough to do the job. Packages the solution and then prepare to ship for deployment (minifi assets for distribution).